# Trying to access array offset on value of type null in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have two table with relationship one table is category and the other is subcategory I need to display all categories and subcategories at a time in a blade, here below is my blade template, subcategory controller and and subcategory model. But when I run this I get the error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null " Please how do I solve this

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\Category;
    use App\Models\SubCategory;
    
    class SubCategoryController extends Controller
    {
         public function AllSubCategory(){
            $subcategories = SubCategory::latest()->get();
            return view('backend.subcategory.subcategory_all',compact('subcategories'));
        }//end method
    
        public function AddSubCategory(){
    
            $categories = Category::orderBy('category_name','ASC')->get();
            return view('backend.subcategory.subcategory_add',compact('categories'));
        }//end method


    @extends('admin.admin_dashboard')
@section('admin')

<div class="page-content">
                <!--breadcrumb-->
                <div class="page-breadcrumb d-none d-sm-flex align-items-center mb-3">
                    <div class="breadcrumb-title pe-3">All SubCategory</div>
                    <div class="ps-3">
                        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                            <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0 p-0">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript:;"><i class="bx bx-home-alt"></i></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">All SubCategory</li>
                            </ol>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ms-auto">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a href="{{route('add.subcategory')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add SubCategory</a>
                            
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--end breadcrumb-->
                
                <hr/>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SN</th>
                                        <th>Category Name</th>
                                        <th>SubCategory Name</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                
                                <tbody>
                                    @foreach($subcategories as $key => $item)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
                                      
                                       <td>{{$item['category']['category_name']}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$item->subcategory_name}}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="{{route('edit.subcategory',$item->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                                            <a href="{{route('delete.subcategory',$item->id)}}" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</a>
                                        </td>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                    
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>SN</th>
                                        <th>Category Name</th>
                                        <th>SubCategory Name</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
@endsection

        <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class SubCategory extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $guarded = [];
    
        public function category(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is triggering that error? I assume `$item['category']['category_name']`. If  `$item['category']` is `null`, then `['category_name']` will trigger that error. Syntax _should_ be `$item->category->category_name`, but that will trigger a similar error. You need to check if `$item->category` is not `null`, like `@if($item->category) {{ $item->category->category->name }} @else No Category @endif`

Comment: This is what I get after  checking

No Category No Category No Category No Category No Category Methmatics Methmatics Methmatics Methmatics Methmatics Physics Physics Physics Physics Physics. There is data but why that error appear

Comment: Looks correct to me! You have a lot of `SubCategory` records that don't have an associated `Category`. So you either need to fix your bad data, or use this check to avoid trying to access something that doesn't exist. *"There is data"* - Not for all of them! *"why that error appear"* - You're trying to access properties of `null`, which doesn't work. When looping, never **assume** that each instance of `$item` will be the same. You can validate it and enforce it, but with the code you wrote, you were assuming, and it blew up in your face. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank -Tim Lewis, I have truncate subcategory table and inserted fresh data and the problem has been fixed

Comment: Excellent! Sidenote, you can also enforce this, like `$subcategories = SubCategory::has('category')->latest()->get();`; That `has()` clause will only return records where `$item->category` is `true`, but having clean, validated and consistent data will always be better than programming workarounds. Cheers!

Comment: Thank -Tim Lewis got it bro